# No database found by BaseX GUI -- yet it shows from the console

Tags: java, database, user-interface, console, basex

After running a Java application which **only** queries a database I look in the `BaseX` console for that database in vain:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$ basex
[warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/jing.jar in /usr/share/java
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> LIST
Name       Resources  Size   Input Path                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
books      1          61253  /home/thufir/basex/db.books.xml      
bookstore  1          6164   /home/thufir/basex/db.bookstore.xml  

2 database(s).
> 
> exit
See you.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$
```

Notably, the database is available through the GUI.  That is, this database was created through Java, queried through Java, is available through the GUI, yet doesn't appear available through the console.

There would appear to very different levels of access.

How would I create a database in the console which is available through the GUI?  And, vice versa?

[image: database present]

[image: no database]

Short of creating a video it's hard to explain.  why is there a discrepancy between the console and GUI?

Comment: Where did the `DROP DB w3school_data` come from in the Info window pane?

Comment: From Java code:  https://github.com/THUFIR/helloWorldBaseX  which can fetch, populate, or, just query.  In that case, it was fetched and then put in the database.  the GUI is consistent with output from that program.  The console is odd man out.  Perhaps it's a server configuration?

Comment: So, after `BaseX/GUI` Info shows `Database 'w3school_data' was dropped.`, this same database appears in the `LIST` of `basex`?

Comment: `w3school_data`, or any db created through Java, never shows in the console where the `LIST` command is executed.  Similarly, what shows from `LIST` is **not** reflected in the GUI where I can click the "database" icon to load a db.  Two distinct systems??

Comment: I imagine this is a path-to-the-databases issue.  I always use the default from the GUI but I know [it can be configured](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Configuration).